# Free tool to convert XSD to HTML

Tags: html, xsd

Is there good freeware tool that will help me convert XSD to HTML?

Comment: What's the purpose of converting XSD to HTML?  Any web browser should display an XSD.  I'm not following the need for a conversion to html

Comment: XSD is for verification of XML to ensure that it is valid. Do you mean XML? In which case look into XSLT.

Comment: @BenAlabaster Perhaps the OP is after the same thing that brought me here; a means of generating an HTML form from an XSD. I'm woking on a PHP library for this purpose, but have been on the hunt for something complete also.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fully automated method, but:
Open any XML file with XSL in Internet Explorer, and then View Source. The source will be in HTML. Other browsers just give the XML back when you View Source.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSL to transform your XSD into (X)HTML. [This](http://serprest.pt/ws/xsd2forms/xsl/simple.xsl) stylesheet creates HTML forms from XSDs for example. But it really depends on what exactly you want to do.